# What's the Scottish equivalent of "holy crap!" "oh my God!" "Jesus Christ!", etc?

Tags: dialects, exclamations, british-english, scottish-english

No swear words, please (sorry).  It's for a YA fantasy that takes place on Skye (modern day), and has to be something a teenager might say (again, yeah, I know.  Swearing.  But surely there's something?).

CLARIFICATION: by "swear" I mean "four-letter-type curse words." I've had some people very concerned with semantics on another board point out (so helpfully) that "holy crap" and "Jesus Christ" ARE swear words. =/

Also, I'd like it to be uniquely Scottish.  This is for a story, and it's meant to differentiate Scottish characters from American and Irish characters.  So something universal that anyone would use as an exclamation won't serve to differentiate.

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssme-8fnTPM

Comment: Present day, or period? If the latter, what century? (I'm not saying I have answers.)

Comment: Mick, good point - I added clarification to the question (it's modern day).

Comment: Does it have to be unique to Scotland, or just something that might be said by Scottish youth?

Comment: I guess... something unique to Scotland?  Counterquestion: what's something that might be said by a Scottish youth that isn't unique to Scotland nor is it any of the things I listed in my question above?

Comment: The young Scots I work with in Glasgow mostly use 'Jesus Christ' to express surprise. In ten years living here, I can't think of ever hearing an English speaking Scot use any 'uniquely Scottish' curses.

Comment: Bodie, how much are you offering anyone here to do your homework for you, please? I think your request is wholly inappropriate.  
Either way there’s no debate about them; they might be as natural to you as breathing and still, *holy crap* and *Jesus Christ* and anything comparable are profanities.

Comment: Robbie, my question is far from 'wholly inappropriate.'  You have shunted aside content, getting hung up on whether or not crap and Christ are profanities. But that doesn't make it inappropriate (or impossible to answer). "Doing your homework for you" implies I ought to be able to do this myself but instead am making you (for free, no less!)  But that's how this works: people ask Qs and others (more helpful than you) try to answer them. I CAN'T do this myself, b/c I'm not Scottish/in Scotland/can easily contact Scotland. All this to say: you are both wrong AND terribly unhelpful.  Thx, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Astonishment, Horror, Surprise**

Your exclamations express astonishment, horror, and surprise.

**Jings and Crivvens**

Scottish exclamations that express astonishment, horror, and surprise, are as follows:

*Jings*

[Jings](https://www.lexico.com/definition/jings) is a late 18th century alteration of Jingo which is today mainly used by Scots to express surprise.

*Crivvens*

[Crivvens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crivvens#:%7E:text=early%2020th%20century.-,Interjection,exclamation%20of%20astonishment%20or%20horror.) is chiefly a Scots word attested to in English since the early 20th century which is used as an exclamation of astonishment or horror.

Comment: To me (and The Broons) these are very Scottish but very mild and do not seem to replicate the strength of feeling that the OP requires.

Comment: @Greybeard The OP has asked for no swear words, and also to take in to consideration that the speaker is a teenager.

Comment: I've never heard a modern Scottish teens use either of those.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be a good writer I suggest doing some research of your own. Read some books or watch some movies set in the place and time you want.

To get you started I'll point out that Scottish teens are going to use most of the same words that English ones do, thanks to universal media.

However a popular word is "shite", meaning essentially the same as "shit" while being distinctly Scottish (although popular in Ireland too).

As in:

> Holy shite, what *is* that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something to consider first is that generally people from Scotland (and other English speaking countries) don't express surprise in the same tone as for example the USA. People are by nature a bit more sarcastic in their speech, and so rather than an exclamation like those (though "Jesus Christ" does get a fair bit of use, and "Oh My God" with younger people), maybe it would be more appropriate to use a dryer phrase like "You've got to be joking / You can't be serious / etc."

How about as an alternative taking one of those phrases but rewriting it as would be said in a Scottish accent / slang now and again, while keeping it readable for other audiences? e.g. can't/isn't ->
"I cannae believe it." "This cannae be happening." "This isnae real."

Also Scotland has a particular rhyming slang, similar to Cockney, which may be of use: http://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/a-guide-to-scottish-rhyming-slang-1-4018992